# Better and shorter phrasing than "With or Without"

Tags: word-choice, grammar, word-usage, phrases, phrase-requests

I'm working on creatives for one of my products. Within this product I have a feature that allow users to repost from Facebook. When the user repost he has the option to "keep"/"add" the Watermark from the original user, or he can leave the Watermark section blanked, no watermark.

From a research I've made some users looking for Watermark, tho most of them looking for No Watermark.
I'm trying to understand what would be the correct phrasing for a case like that, containing the need both for the "I need watermark" users and for the "I want no watermark on my repost" users. **The creative is limited in spacing, so shorten phrases are highly preferable. 4 words max.**

A few ideas came to my mind:

- Customisable Watermark
- Remove or Keep Watermark
- With or Without Watermark

But I'm not a native speaker, so i'm sure there is a better and **shorter** options.

What are your thoughts?

Comment: He word you want is ***optional***, or any of the synonyms listed for that word in a thesaurus.

Comment: Hey @DanBron , thank you for replying! You mean that "Optional Watermark" is the needed Phrase? Is it explicit enough for your opinion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before I add my own alternatives to wording an option for a case like this, I'd like to tell you that your ones would perfectly do the job. The first one does seem very official to me, like a caption from Microsoft Office Word, whereas the last two (especially the last one) are kind of not that formal. Remember, it is only my opinion.

- Watermark ON or OFF
- Optional Watermark
- Watermark to be chosen

They are of only three, but I hope they helped.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for a form label or a word that might be understood in an array of optional attributes ?
Is it a variable name for a boolean or a 'tag-name' ?
Would you like the ability for more than a boolean answer to the same human readable trait ?

I might suggest "**Watermarked**" for a condition name.

variable name "watermarked" would suggest both purpose and state ...

It would lead to strong presumption that it would be a boolean however .. depending on the language you used and your workflow conventions.  If you are strict naming booleans like *isWatermarked* or *watermarked?* that would be less an issue.

With a "watermarked" named condition, it could instead be one of a set of string conditions that might be expanded "original watermark" , "watermark removed" , "no watermark" ?

The term could work nicely if it were only included in an array of attributes in the included state too.